# How does the voltage drop to negative values at t = 0 when the voltage starts with 0 V?

Tags: voltage, dc, inductor

I understand that the voltage in the inductor is 0V because it behaves as a wire with a constant dc source while the switch is closed. But why does it drop to a negative value  when the time t = 0 and the switch opens, instead of remaining as zero? [image]

Comment: ...voltage starts  with 0V...". No. In t=0, the voltage has a discontinuity, from 0 V to -IL0(5k + 15k) V, growing exponentially to 0 V. The IL0 is the current flowing through inductor in t= 0-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The current after the switch opens.*

You can think of an inductor as liking to maintain the current through it - in the short-term at least. The result of this is that at the moment you open the switch that current reverses through the 5k resistor.

Now observe that since current is flowing clockwise around the loop and the polarity of the voltage across the resistors will be as shown.

Finally, since the bottom of the inductor and 5k resistor are tied to GND and the right side of the 15k is negative then to top of the inductor must be negative too.

Comment: For those who visualize things mathematically, the inductor current must be continuous; the derivative of the inductor must be finite (because the voltage across the inductor is proportional to the derivative of the current).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at it:

We close the switch, and the voltage across the inductor jumps to 80V×5/7, and then decay to zero. There is no asymmetry in the circuit. So when we open the switch the voltage, across the inductor, will jump to ????, and then decay to zero.

Clue

- the opposite of close, is open
- the opposite of 80V×5/7 is ????

Answer (score -1):

Because the current through the inductor is still flowing and it is flowing through the 5k and 15k resistor. Current always flows to the more negative side and because the coil is pulling the current from the top to the bottom, the voltage on the top has to be more negative than on the bottom.

Comment: RE "Current always flows to the more negative side"... the more negative side of what? Through what kinds of components? This is true for resistors, but not for things like batteries or (in this example) inductors.

Comment: This is confusing. "flows to the more negative side"...from outside the inductor toward the more negative side or within the inductor? How does an inductor "pull" current?

Comment: The inductor has some stored energy in its magnetic field (and a very small amount of energy in electric fields arrayed between the various turns of wire inside the inductor). When that switch opens, the current tries to abruptly change (slowed only by the need to reverse the electric fields between the turns of wire), and then the stored energy of the magnetic field comes into action and opposes the attempt to abruptly change the current. If needed, **all** the stored energy will be spent (often as an arc or spark) in sustaining the previous current.